# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error

I am start getting this error suddenly how i can resolve this inorder my site work fine:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'yukamagentonew'@'173.201.196.168' for table 'core_resource'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a database error, which means that the user `yukamagentonew` has no access to the `core_resource` table.

To fix this, you'll have to review your database permissions and change them. If this happens suddenly, probably someone changed the permissions for your database.

If you can't fix it yourself, maybe you could ask your hosting provider to help you.